# select mutiple rows from single column

Tags: sql

I have two tables tickets and tickets events

tickets

```
t-number  t_street, t_zone,name
888        xyz           abc
999         ddd          rrr
1000        eee          fff
```

tickets _events

```
te_system_ref    te_event_code te_event          te_userid
888               13000         off hold          autodrop
888               11000         disocunt          autodrop
888               10000         on hold              autodrop
999                13000        offfhold          smrithi
1000               11000        disocunt          keerthi
```

I need to find out which te_system_ref has both the the te_events 13000 and 11000

```
SELECT  *
  FROM ticket_events as a 
  inner join tickets as b on
 b.t_number = a.te_system_ref
   where 
  te_event_code = '13000'  and //te_event_code in('13000','11000') or te_event in ('off hold' , 'disocunt')
  te_userid = 'AUTODROP'
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *exists* construction here

```
select *
  from te_system_ref tsr 
         inner join
       tickets t 
         on (tsr.te_system_ref = t.t_number)
 where exists (select 1
                 from tickets_events te
                where te.te_system_ref = t.t_number and
                      te.te_event_code = 11000) and
       exists (select 1
                 from tickets_events te
                where te.te_system_ref = t.t_number and
                      te.te_event_code = 13000)
```

Comment: how can i get te_event_code  columnn in select statment

Comment: @smrithi: Sorry, see my edit: just add inner join to show ticket_events' columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Select te_system_ref
From ickets _events
Where te_event_code in('13000','11000')
      And te_userid = 'AUTODROP'
Group By te_system_ref
Having Count(*)=2
```

Comment: What if '11000' appeared twice on some ticket, but '13000' didn't appear at all? The Count(*) will be 2. What if '11000' appeared 3 times on some ticket and '13000' appeared 4 times? The Count(*) will be 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select te_system_ref
From table1
Where te_userid = 'AUTODROP'
Group By te_system_ref
Having sum((case when te_event_code='13000' then 1 else 0 end)+
           (case when te_event_code='11000' then 1 else 0 end))=2
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7d50/6)